# Globally accessible function without initialisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible in Rails to have a "simple" function that is globally accessible?

```
do_something
```

> => "Of course"

I've tried adding an instance method to the Object class, but that adds that method to everything.

Comment: Do you mean a globally-accessible method? IMO, that doesn't seem very rubyish. Perhaps create a class with the desired method as a class method - something like `Foo.do_something`?

Comment: Yea I know, this is very unrubyish. But (if it's technically possible) I still want it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just declare a method on Main (which is the global scope in Ruby) at any point in your application:

```
# config/application.rb
# ...
def do_something  
end
```

You can reference the method explicitly with `::do_something` but with the way that module nesting works in ruby any call will go up the module nesting to Main anyways.

Still is a dumb idea though as the code will not be reloaded in development and pollutes the global namespace. And since Main is on the module nesting of everything just like object you're adding a `do_something` method to all the objects in the system.

If you want to avoid that you would have to create a lambda/proc assigned to a global/constant:

```
$do_something = ->{}
DO_SOMETHING = ->{}
```

Or just grow up and encapsulate your method in a module/class.